# how to toggle between symbols and numbers in html css js created keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have followed a video and created this virtual keyboard and learned so much up until now.
In the created keyboard I want to know how to replace the "done" key  to toggle a row of symbols instead of closing the keyboard.

I also want it to toggle back to alphabetic keyboard when clicking on any key on the symbol layout.

I am stuck on changing the layout.

```js
const Keyboard = {
  elements: {
    main: null,
    keysContainer: null,
    keys: []
  },

  eventHandlers: {
    oninput: null,
    onclose: null
  },

  properties: {
    value: "",
    capsLock: false
  },

  init() {
    // Create main elements
    this.elements.main = document.createElement("div");
    this.elements.keysContainer = document.createElement("div");

    // Setup main elements
    this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard", "keyboard--hidden");
    this.elements.keysContainer.classList.add("keyboard__keys");
    this.elements.keysContainer.appendChild(this._createKeys());



    this.elements.keys = this.elements.keysContainer.querySelectorAll(".keyboard__key");

    // Add to DOM
    this.elements.main.appendChild(this.elements.keysContainer);
    document.body.appendChild(this.elements.main);

    // Automatically use keyboard for elements with .use-keyboard-input
    document.querySelectorAll(".use-keyboard-input").forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener("focus", () => {
        this.open(element.value, currentValue => {
          element.value = currentValue;
        });
      });
    });
  },

  _createKeys() {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const keyLayout = [
      "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "backspace",
      "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
      "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "enter",
      "done", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
      "space"
    ];
    const SymbolLayout = [
      "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "backspace",
      "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
      "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "enter",
      "done", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
      "space"
    ];

    // Creates HTML for an icon
    const createIconHTML = (icon_name) => {
      return `<i class="material-icons">${icon_name}</i>`;
    };

    keyLayout.forEach(key => {
      const keyElement = document.createElement("button");
      const insertLineBreak = ["backspace", "p", "enter", "?"].indexOf(key) !== -1;


      // Add attributes/classes
      keyElement.setAttribute("type", "button");
      keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key");

      switch (key) {
        case "backspace":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("backspace");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value = this.properties.value.substring(0, this.properties.value.length - 1);
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "caps":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--activatable");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_capslock");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this._toggleCapsLock();
            keyElement.classList.toggle("keyboard__key--active", this.properties.capsLock);
          });

          break;

        case "enter":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_return");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += "\n";
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "space":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--extra-wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("space_bar");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += " ";
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "done":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--dark");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("check_circle");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.close();
            this._triggerEvent("onclose");
          });

          break;

        default:
          keyElement.textContent = key.toLowerCase();

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += this.properties.capsLock ? key.toUpperCase() : key.toLowerCase();
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;
      }

      fragment.appendChild(keyElement);

      if (insertLineBreak) {
        fragment.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      }
    });

    return fragment;
  },

  _triggerEvent(handlerName) {
    if (typeof this.eventHandlers[handlerName] == "function") {
      this.eventHandlers[handlerName](this.properties.value);
    }
  },

  _toggleCapsLock() {
    this.properties.capsLock = !this.properties.capsLock;

    for (const key of this.elements.keys) {
      if (key.childElementCount === 0) {
        key.textContent = this.properties.capsLock ? key.textContent.toUpperCase() : key.textContent.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  },

  open(initialValue, oninput, onclose) {
    this.properties.value = initialValue || "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
    this.elements.main.classList.remove("keyboard--hidden");
  },

  close() {
    this.properties.value = "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
    this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard--hidden");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  Keyboard.init();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background: rgb(54, 49, 49);
}

.use-keyboard-input {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.678);
  border: 2px solid rgb(107, 104, 104);
  border-radius: 10%;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.keyboard {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: transparent;
  user-select: none;
  transition: bottom 0.4s;
}

.keyboard--hidden {
  bottom: -100%;
}

.keyboard__keys {
  text-align: center;
}

.keyboard__key {
  height: 45px;
  width: 6%;
  max-width: 90px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(218, 190, 218, 0.589);
  color: #0c0101;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.keyboard__key::after {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.keyboard__key:active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.keyboard__key--wide {
  width: 12%;
}

.keyboard__key--extra-wide {
  width: 36%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.keyboard__key--dark {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Virtual Keyboard using HTML5 &amp; JS Example</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Codeconvey" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="rt-container">
      <div class="col-rt-12">
        <div class="Scriptcontent">
          <h1>Click Here to Type</h1>
          <textarea class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea>

          <script src="js/keyboard.js"></script>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When adding Snippets, please tidy your code by removing extra empty lines and clicking the "Tidy" button.

Comment: Please read [How much effort is expected of Stack overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do is have the Keyboard layout become a parameter of the function instead... That way your code could do any keyboard, or almost because the actions will remain hardcoded.

```js
const keyLayout = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "backspace",
  "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
  "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "enter",
  "done", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
  "space"
];
const SymbolLayout = [
  "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "backspace",
  "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
  "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "enter",
  "done", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
  "space"
];

const Keyboard = {
  elements: {
    main: null,
    keysContainer: null,
    keys: []
  },

  eventHandlers: {
    oninput: null,
    onclose: null
  },

  properties: {
    value: "",
    capsLock: false
  },

  init() {
    // Create main elements
    this.elements.main = document.createElement("div");
    this.elements.keysContainer = document.createElement("div");

    // Setup main elements
    this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard", "keyboard--hidden");
    this.elements.keysContainer.classList.add("keyboard__keys");
    this.setLayout(keyLayout);

    // Add to DOM
    this.elements.main.appendChild(this.elements.keysContainer);
    document.body.appendChild(this.elements.main);

    // Automatically use keyboard for elements with .use-keyboard-input
    document.querySelectorAll(".use-keyboard-input").forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener("focus", () => {
        this.open(element.value, currentValue => {
          element.value = currentValue;
        });
      });
    });
  },
  setLayout(layout) {
    this.elements.keysContainer.innerHTML = "";
    this.elements.keysContainer.appendChild(this._createKeys(layout));
    this.elements.keys = this.elements.keysContainer.querySelectorAll(".keyboard__key");
  },
  _createKeys(layout) {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // Creates HTML for an icon
    const createIconHTML = (icon_name) => {
      return `<i class="material-icons">${icon_name}</i>`;
    };

    layout.forEach(key => {
      const keyElement = document.createElement("button");
      const insertLineBreak = ["backspace", "p", "enter", "?"].indexOf(key) !== -1;


      // Add attributes/classes
      keyElement.setAttribute("type", "button");
      keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key");

      switch (key) {
        case "backspace":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("backspace");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value = this.properties.value.substring(0, this.properties.value.length - 1);
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "caps":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--activatable");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_capslock");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this._toggleCapsLock();
            keyElement.classList.toggle("keyboard__key--active", this.properties.capsLock);
          });

          break;

        case "enter":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_return");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += "\n";
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "space":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--extra-wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("space_bar");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += " ";
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "done":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--dark");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("check_circle");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            //this.close();
            this.setLayout(SymbolLayout);
            //this._triggerEvent("onclose");
          });

          break;

        default:
          keyElement.textContent = key.toLowerCase();

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += this.properties.capsLock ? key.toUpperCase() : key.toLowerCase();
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;
      }

      fragment.appendChild(keyElement);

      if (insertLineBreak) {
        fragment.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      }
    });

    return fragment;
  },

  _triggerEvent(handlerName) {
    if (typeof this.eventHandlers[handlerName] == "function") {
      this.eventHandlers[handlerName](this.properties.value);
    }
  },

  _toggleCapsLock() {
    this.properties.capsLock = !this.properties.capsLock;

    for (const key of this.elements.keys) {
      if (key.childElementCount === 0) {
        key.textContent = this.properties.capsLock ? key.textContent.toUpperCase() : key.textContent.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  },

  open(initialValue, oninput, onclose) {
    this.properties.value = initialValue || "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
    this.elements.main.classList.remove("keyboard--hidden");
  },

  close() {
    this.properties.value = "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
    this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard--hidden");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  Keyboard.init();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background: rgb(54, 49, 49);
}

.use-keyboard-input {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.678);
  border: 2px solid rgb(107, 104, 104);
  border-radius: 10%;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.keyboard {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: transparent;
  user-select: none;
  transition: bottom 0.4s;
}

.keyboard--hidden {
  bottom: -100%;
}

.keyboard__keys {
  text-align: center;
}

.keyboard__key {
  height: 45px;
  width: 6%;
  max-width: 90px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(218, 190, 218, 0.589);
  color: #0c0101;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.keyboard__key::after {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.keyboard__key:active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.keyboard__key--wide {
  width: 12%;
}

.keyboard__key--extra-wide {
  width: 36%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.keyboard__key--dark {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Virtual Keyboard using HTML5 &amp; JS Example</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Codeconvey" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="rt-container">
      <div class="col-rt-12">
        <div class="Scriptcontent">
          <h1>Click Here to Type</h1>
          <textarea class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea>

          <script src="js/keyboard.js"></script>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

So I added setLayout function, that receives a layout and applies it using _createKeys

I then added the call to setLayout in the done key event.

If you want my advice, I'd get rid of all the events on each keys and instead put one on the container that fires when the target of the click is the child keys. Use innerText or maybe data attributes on keys to be able to identify it. Then emit an event on the keyboard that could be listened to, that way you don't touch your keyboard code to add functionalities on clicks.

Comment: thank you for your answer it did help me activate symbols but it doesn't toggle between symbols and numbers.could you please show me how to that too?

Comment: i have created another button in the keylayout and named it numbers and added keylayout to be activated as the event when clicked now i can use the two but i think there should be a better way

Comment: Please bro check your code, when clicking back on the button it doesn't changes special characters to number's one

Comment: Hello, the code was not supposed to do everything, just to show how this could be done.